# My sql query is executing in sql server management studio but giving error when executuing from .net application. It gives type casting error

Tags: sql-server

```
WITH TEMP_CTE (ID,currentposition,equiptmentno,isocode,carrier,ishazardous,isreefer,CallID)
AS
(
        SELECT a.ID,
               a.newposition AS currentposition, 
               qce.equiptmentno, 
               qce.isocode,  
               qce.carrier,  
               qcee.ishazardous, 
               qcee.isreefer,qce.CallID
        FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY callequipmentid 
                           ORDER BY e.movedate DESC) RN, 
                       e.* 
                FROM   qbtcallequipmentexecution e 
                WHERE  e.isactive = 1)a 
               INNER JOIN qbtcallequipment AS qce 
                       ON a.callequipmentid = qce.id 
                          AND qce.callid = @CallID 
                          AND a.rn = 1 
                          AND operationtype = 'LOAD' 
               INNER JOIN qbtcallediequipment AS qcee 
                       ON qcee.equiptmentno = qce.equiptmentno 
               INNER JOIN qbtcalledi qcd 
                       ON qcee.callediid = qcd.id 
                          AND qcd.callid = @CallID 
               INNER JOIN commlov cl 
                       ON cl.id = qcd.editypeid 
                          AND cl.code = 'MOVINS' 
                          AND siteid = @SiteID 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT ddqce.ID,
               ddqce.currentposition AS currentposition, 
               dqcee.equiptmentno, 
               dqcee.isocode,  
               dqcee.carrier, 
               dqcee.ishazardous, 
               dqcee.isreefer,ddqce.CallID
        FROM   qbtcallediequipment AS dqcee 
               INNER JOIN qbtcalledi dqcd 
                       ON dqcee.callediid = dqcd.id 
                          AND dqcd.callid = @CallID 
               INNER JOIN commlov dcl 
                       ON dcl.id = dqcd.editypeid 
                          AND dcl.code = 'RDBAPL' 
                          AND siteid = @SiteID 
               INNER JOIN qbtcallequipment ddqce 
                       ON ddqce.equiptmentno = dqcee.equiptmentno 
                          AND ddqce.callid = @CallID 
                          AND ddqce.isactive = 1 
        WHERE  dqcee.equiptmentno NOT IN (SELECT dqce.equiptmentno 
                                          FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                                                           OVER ( 
                                                             partition BY 
                                                           callequipmentid 
                                                             ORDER BY e.movedate DESC) 
                                                         RN, 
                                                         e.* 
                                                  FROM   qbtcallequipmentexecution e 
                                                  WHERE  e.isactive = 1)a 
                                                 INNER JOIN qbtcallequipment dqce 
                                                         ON a.callequipmentid = dqce.id 
                                                            AND dqce.callid = @CallID 
                                                            AND a.rn = 1 
                                                            AND movetypeid = (SELECT id 
                                                                              FROM 
                                                                commlov 
                                                                              WHERE 
                                                                code = 
                                                                             'DSCR' 
                                                                                     AND 
                                                                siteid = 
                                                                @SiteID)) 
),
FIRST_CTE 
AS
(
    select ID,currentposition,equiptmentno,isocode,carrier,ishazardous,isreefer,CallID, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by currentposition order by equiptmentno desc ) as RN from TEMP_CTE
),
SECOND_CTE
AS
(
    select TC.ID,currentposition,equiptmentno,isocode,carrier,ishazardous,isreefer,CallID,'Flying' as Anomaly
    from TEMP_CTE as TC
        inner join schmtVesselSchedule svs on svs.ID=TC.CallID 
        inner join qbtVesselProfile AS QVP ON svs.VesselID=QVP.VesselID
    WHERE (cast(RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2) as int)>2 AND cast(RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2) as int)<cast(QVP.MaxTierUnderDeck as int)) OR (cast (RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2) as int)>cast (QVP.StartNoOverDeck as int) AND cast (RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2) as int) < cast (QVP.EndNoOverDeck as int)) AND (LEFT(TC.currentposition, LEN(cast(TC.currentposition as int)-2)+(case when LEN(cast(RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2) as int)-2)=1 then '0'+CONVERT(varchar(10), (RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2)-2)) else CONVERT(varchar(10), (RIGHT(TC.currentposition,2)-2))  end )) is null)
)
select 
     ID,
     currentposition,
     equiptmentno,
     isocode,
     carrier,
     ishazardous,
     isreefer,CallID,(case when RIGHT(currentposition,2)='99' then 'Dummy' else 'Same Slot' end) as Anomaly
 from FIRST_CTE where RN > 1 OR RIGHT(currentposition,2) = '99'
 union all
 select 
     ID,
     currentposition,
     equiptmentno,
     isocode,
     carrier,
     ishazardous,
     isreefer,CallID,Anomaly
 from SECOND_CTE
```

*Error comes in where condition of SECOND_CTE. In that i used temp_cte for data purpose and manupulate it  over there. Giving Error "*

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'RT' to data type
>   int

. I have changed data type nvarchar to varchar of that column it also not working.And there is not char value in that column. It works fine in ssms but not working from Visual Studio"

Comment: Don't compare strings (char/varchar) with ints - SQL Server will always try to convert this pairing *to* an integer, which can fail at runtime. If it "works from Visual Studio" the query is *not running against the same data (or @params)*, because that error is *from SQL Server itself*.

Comment: While this error *probably* indicates an error in the data (and types used in the join - where is 'RT' coming from, and *why* is it being compared to an integer?), it will "work" - or rather, "not fail" with a SQL conversion error - if explicitly converting the int type-value to a char first.

Comment: Also, make sure the `@variables` are *bound to correctly typed values* when the SQL is invoked.

Comment: Here is a good reading on datatype conversions: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-data-conversion-horribly-wrong/

Comment: I've voted to close because it's too much of a wall of text. Isolate the *exact part* that fails along with necessary *reproduction data* in a minimal failure case. Good luck!

Comment: There's a lot of places where this could be failing, but without being able to actually run SQL to reproduce, this is going to be guesswork. Somewhere your trying to compare (or combine) a integer value to a varchar value of 'RT'. Now, this could be in one of your `ON` clauses, or your `WHERE`. You also, however, have some `UNION ALL`'s in there, so if you have an integer column and `UNION` to a varchar (that doesn't have a integer value), you'll get the same error. For example `SELECT 10 AS I UNION SELECT 'RT' AS I;`. We can't reproduce this, so it's up to you and some trial and error.

Comment: But my data is correct , If i remove where condition from SECOND_CTE block then query work fine. and currentposition from TEMP_CTE block contains all varchar with no only

Comment: What is the type of MaxTierUnderDeck/StartNoOverDeck/EndNoOverDeck?

Comment: thanks For the help . these are int Datatype. issue is resolved